# Unable to Search Filter in flatlist (React-native)

Tags: android, reactjs, api, react-native

I have created android app where i fetch my api ()and render flatlist. This is the image. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/MbtLR.jpg). But then when i search the title in the flatlist it show me blank flatlist (https://i.stack.imgur.com/EagBA.jpg)
Below are my code how i search

```
type Props = {};
export default class IndexScreen extends Component<Props> {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Announcements',
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      data: [],
      isFetching: false,
      search: ''
    };
    this.arrayholder = [];

    this._load = this._load.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this._load();
  }
  SearchFilterFunction(text) {
    //passing the inserted text in textinput
    const newData = this.arrayholder.filter(function(item) {
      //applying filter for the inserted text in search bar
      const itemData = item.title ? item.title.toUpperCase() : ''.toUpperCase();
      const textData = text.toUpperCase();
      return itemData.indexOf(textData) > -1;
    });
    this.setState({
      //setting the filtered newData on datasource
      //After setting the data it will automatically re-render the view
      data: newData,
      text: text,
    });
  }

  _load() {
    this.setState({isFetching: true});

    fetch("http://lkcfesnotification.000webhostapp.com/api/notifications")
    .then((response) => {
      if(!response.ok) {
        Alert.alert('Error', response.status.toString());
        throw Error('Error ' + response.status);
      }

      return response.json()
    })
.then(({ data }) => {
    this.setState({data});
    this.setState({isFetching: false});
            this.arrayholder = responseJson;
})
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error)
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TextInput
          style={styles.textInputStyle}
          onChangeText={text => this.SearchFilterFunction(text)}
          value={this.state.text}
          underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
          placeholder="Search Here"
        />
    <FlatList
      data={this.state.data}
      showsVerticalScrollIndicator={true}
      refreshing={this.state.isFetching}
      onRefresh={this._load}
      renderItem={({item}) =>
        <TouchableHighlight
          underlayColor={'#cccccc'}
          onPress={() => {
            this.props.navigation.navigate('Show', {
              id: item.id,
              headerTitle: item.title,
              refresh: this._load,
            })
          }}
        >
          <View style={styles.item}>
            <Text style={styles.itemTitle}>{item.department}</Text>
            <Text style={styles.itemSubtitle}>{item.title}</Text>
          </View>
        </TouchableHighlight>
      }
      keyExtractor={(item) => {item.id.toString()}}
    />
```

The output i expected was when i search the word ("UTAR") all the flatlist with utar shows up

Comment: Please add your FlatList code

Comment: verify that your SearchText filter method getting filter data ? have you console it and verify the values

Comment: @WasiqMuhammad no because it enter empty everytime

Answer (score 0):

OK i did solve this issue by myself
the error was i don't have any data in my array which my original array was data instead of arrayholder. But i need to change to this.state.data in order this to work which will change the value of the entire flatlist. But when i use this.data it show error of the object data is undefined